# Is there report size limit in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

While checking Power BI workspace I noticed that few reports are not refreshed. Checking the details, I found following:

[image]

Is there any size limit on individual report? We are using Power BI Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Pro license has limit of [10 GB for storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi), but the screenshot points to a gateway error, i.e. you should check the disk space on the computer, where this gateway is installed.

Comment: Thank you for update 
While checking the space on server each driver is having more than 20 GB space, Anything else i should check ?